# How to fix my project to be correctly opened by Blender versions newer than 2.82a?

Tags: blend-files, versions

I had some issues with my project created in Blender 2.82a, which is not being correctly opened by newer versions.

I created a ticket (https://developer.blender.org/T78960)  and there it was told be that "*the problem is actually that your Cantos collection has an empty instancing that collection, this creates a very bad infinite loop.*" (https://developer.blender.org/T78960#989403).

However I don't know how to fix this error, so I always have to use 2.82a to open these projects.

Could anyone download the project (it's in the original ticket above) and show me what I have to do to fix it to be correctly opened by newer Blender versions?

Answer (score 2):

The problem has to do with an empty that is in a collection attached to your Cantos object that cannot be opened to alter the contents (presumably because the empty is instancing it's own parent collection - there's your infinite loop). The solution, then, is to delete it, as I cannot see what function it serves other than causing problems (although you may have a different reason for needing it). However, the collection also contains a mesh that is the counterpart to the one on the other side. We'll deal with that in a minute.

First start by finding and deleting the offending collection:

[image: Broke1]

You will see that this removes the clamp, and also forces the collection to dump it's contents, which in this case is the offending empty. Isolate and delete this too.

[image: Broke2]

To put the clamp back (either in object mode, or edit mode - depending on what you want), I found duplicating and moving by -4.75 units on the X axis puts it right back in place.
Here's a picture from the file open in 2.83.

[image: Fixed2.8]

I'll also post the blend in case you need it quick.

File is here - [image]

Comment: Thanks, but I tried to do the same here and also I downloaded your file and it still not showing the layers (when trying to open it with the lastest 2.83.5): https://i.imgur.com/id9UFl8.png. Have you tried to open your file with 2.83.5?

Comment: No. I tested with base 2.83 LTS. I can't see why it should be that different in 2.83.5 though. I also downloaded the file I uploaded and opened it just to test, and everything's where it should be on my end. I guess the answer lies in something that got changed between 2.83.0 and 2.83.5. I can't see what else it could be though....

Comment: Here exactly when I open the project you sent me with 2.82a: https://i.imgur.com/3Mej4AP.png.
And here when I do the same with 2.83.5 (and it's the same since 2.83.2): https://i.imgur.com/yEivlGL.png

Comment: I would just like to get rid of version 2.82a, but I can't, because these projects are only opened correctly in this version. At the same time, the Blender people don't give me a solution ...

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. I'll keep looking for what's causing this, but I'm a bit at a loss. I'm pretty sure that Cube.001 is a clue, though, because there's a Cube.001 under the Tampa (Cover?) object below it in the scene tree. As far as I know, blender doesn't allow 2 things to be named the same, so they have to be related (instanced perhaps?). Maybe more is being instanced by that empty that I originally thought.

Comment: Here, try this file - just a long shot - tell me if it works any better. - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/YrpbBx2N/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111996/discussion-between-rogerio-dec-and-christopher-bennett).

Answer (score 0):

The Blender Support team found the solution: https://developer.blender.org/T79936#999546